# Странное поведение оператора >>

Tags: c++, json

Решил попробовать в работе библиотеку [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), написал простенькую программу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <json/json.h>
int main() {
    Json::Value val;
    std::cin >> val["foo"]; //вот здесь странно себя ведет.
    std::cout << val;
}
```

Но после компиляции и запуска программа не доходит до вывода `root`, а бесконечно дает вводить текст. Очевидно, проблема в строке `std::cin >> val["foo"]`, но строка взята из примера в документации, и там та же проблема. Даже не могу представить, в чем может быть проблема. [Здесь](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp) в самом низу (последняя функция) можно увидеть реализацию этого самого `operator>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело вот в [этой строке](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp#L1978) в библиотеке:

```
ssin << sin.rdbuf();
```

Это яд: она [пытается скопировать весь файл целиком](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/operator%3C%3C/), поэтому чтобы закончить ввод, вы должны скормить терминалу EOF (^D на никсах, ^Z на Windows). Короче говоря, не используйте эту функцию, а еще лучше не используйте эту библиотеку - [rapidjson](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson), например, не страдает от таких дефектов.